# Scroll wheel doesn't work when cursor is on iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have an iframe with a youtube video inside an html page. When I try scrolling, I cannot scroll while my mouse is over the iframe. I found this question below but param doesn't help me as this is an object and mine is an iframe.

[Avoid scroll-wheel hijack by embedded youtube / flash video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7917498/avoid-scroll-wheel-hijack-by-embedded-youtube-flash-video)

I saw the solution to put an invisible div on top, but that is a problem because the user won't be able to click to pause/play the video.

Does anyone have another solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the iframe with the following:

```
style="pointer-events:none;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try delegating the video play/pause functions to a button somewhere else:

```
var myPlayer = document.getElementById('playerid');
myPlayer.stopVideo();
```

Source: [How can I stop a video with Javascript in Youtube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094397/how-can-i-stop-a-video-with-javascript-in-youtube)